# How do I make a batch script exit if executed by bash?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file

I have a repo that runs a Windows .bat file on build. I'd like it to not do that when I'm on Linux. Is there a trick I can put in the .bat file, or do I have to make the build system deal with this?

Comment: You mean a `Makefile` that runs the Windows .bat file?

Comment: msbuild on a .csproj file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a simple solution, just put the following lines at the head of the .bat file:

```
rem () { echo "Not running prebuild.bat on Linux"; exit 0; }
rem skip prebuild if executed by bash
```